# File input/output

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

Ive been asked my current program to be saved into a file so it can be continued later even if the program end. However I am new to java, so I Would really appreciate if someone can help me on this :) This is the code i manage to get done, however it just creates an empty file,how am I suppose to go about this problem?

Below is not the whole program coding, i've just copied the codes that is relevant.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;


public static void main (String[] param) throws FileNotFoundException
{
 try 
    {
    fileinputoutput ();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
   System.exit(0);
    }
} // END main



public static void fileinputoutput() throws FileNotFoundException
 {

    File input = new File("input.txt");
    File output = new File("loveletter.txt");
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(output);

    Scanner check = new Scanner(System.in);

    String filename = check.nextLine();
    File inputfile = new File(filename);

    Scanner newfile = new Scanner(inputfile);
    newfile.close();

    while(newfile.hasNext())
    {

    String write = newfile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(write);

    }

    outputFile.close();

}
```

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Please be explicit and clear.

Comment: You do know that you're only outputting to ```System.out```?

Comment: @flashdrive2049 post up your answer so I can vote u up

Comment: I am confused myself, I'm doing an exercise which is asking me to save my program into a file, so it can be continued later even if the program ends. And i'm suppose to use file/output. I do not have a clue how to do that :/ @Michal Wilkowski

Comment: I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty obvious. The reason why you only get a blank file is that you never write anything through `outputFile` and close `newfile` before you can do anything with it. You should try something like this:

```java
public static void fileinputoutput() throws FileNotFoundException {
    File input = new File("input.txt"); // What do you use this variable for? It's never used in the code fragment you posted
    File output = new File("loveletter.txt");
    PrintWriter outputFile = new FileWriter(output); // I'd personally use FileWriter here
    Scanner check = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = check.nextLine();
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    Scanner newfile = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while(newfile.hasNext()) {
        String write = newfile.nextLine();
        outputFile.println(write); // You used to only output something to the console here
    }

    outputFile.close();
    newfile.close();
    check.close();
}
```